# Cannot send multiple messages via socket without releasing and re-initialising the socket

Tags: c#, python, sockets

I need to exchange data from two machines with the highest throughput as possible. I have a server and a client.

The client needs to send several messages to the server (in the real application, 1 message every 22 ms). Instead of initializing the socket every time I need to send something, I would like to keep the connection open and to write several messages via socket that will be initialized once for all.

Here's my client in C#:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

// State object for receiving data from remote device.  
public class StateObject
{
    // Client socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
    // The port number for the remote device.  
    private const int port = 11000;

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.  
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // The response from the remote device.  
    private static String response = String.Empty;

    private static Socket InitClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device. 
        // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  
        // The name of the    
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, 
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        { 
            // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
               new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

        }
        return client;
    }

    private static void SendData(Socket client) {
        try {
            // Send test data to the remote device.  
            StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();

            Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            // Receive the response from the remote device.  
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();

            // Write the response to the console.  
            Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

        }

    }

    private static void ReleaseClient(Socket client) {
        try
        {
            // Release the socket.  
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.  
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.  
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.  
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket   
            // from the asynchronous state object.  
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.  
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Get the rest of the data.  
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.  
                if (state.sb.Length >= 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.  
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.  
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {

    Socket client = InitClient();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        SendData(client);
    }

    ReleaseClient(client);
    Console.ReadLine();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the server in Python:

```py
import socketserver 
import socket

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(87380).strip()
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[1]))
        l = (str(len(self.data)))
        print(l)
        self.request.sendall(l.encode())


HOST, PORT = socket.gethostname(), 11000

server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
server.socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
server.serve_forever()
```

I can connect to the server, and if I'm calling this from C#:

```
InitClient(); 
SendData(client); 
ReleaseClient(client);
```

Everything works fine. But if, like in my example, I'm trying to loop over `SendData()`, I can only send the first message and, when trying to send the second, the server gives me the following error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10053): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at AsynchronousClient.Receive(Socket client) in C:\Users\giuli\source\repos\ApplicationSending\ApplicationSending\Program.cs:line 133 (NdR the lines that corresponds to:
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);)
```

I cannot understand what is happening. Shouldn't it be possible to send multiple messages without having to re-initialize the socket?

Comment: Obviously that's how socketserver.TCPServer works... Handle and disconnect ... which is written in documentation

Comment: Thank you Selvin, which method should I use to replace socketserver.TCPServer?

Comment: @JuliusCaesar you don't need to replace it. Just have your `handle()` read data in a loop until the connection is closed. When `handle()` exits, the server closes the connection to the client.

Comment: @RemyLebeau TCPServer is single thread - you should not block it in `handle()` as server will not accept other connections

Comment: @Selvin you can configure TCPServer to run each request in a separate thread or forked process: "*These four classes process requests synchronously; each request must be completed before the next request can be started. This isn’t suitable if each request takes a long time to complete, because it requires a lot of computation, or because it returns a lot of data which the client is slow to process. **The solution is to create a separate process or thread to handle each request; the ForkingMixIn and ThreadingMixIn mix-in classes can be used to support asynchronous behaviour**.*"

Answer (score 0):

This is how we establish the connection and keep sending multiple messages.

```
#Client.cs

private AutoResetEvent[] _autoSendReceiveEvents;

##Connection method
    using (var connectArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs())
    {
        connectArgs.AcceptSocket = _socket;
        connectArgs.RemoteEndPoint = _ipEndPoint;
        connectArgs.Completed += OnCompleted;

        var result = _socket.ConnectAsync(connectArgs);
        if (result)
        {
           _autoConnectEvent.WaitOne();
        }

        var errorCode = connectArgs.SocketError;
        if (errorCode != SocketError.Success)
        {
                CloseSocket();
                throw new SocketException((int) errorCode);
        }
    }
##Sending Data
    public void Send(string message)
        {
            if (!IsConnected)
            {
                throw new SocketException((int) SocketError.NotConnected);
            }

            var sendBuffer = GetBytes(message);
            using (var sendReceiveArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs())
            {
                sendReceiveArgs.SetBuffer(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);
                sendReceiveArgs.AcceptSocket = _socket;
                sendReceiveArgs.RemoteEndPoint = _ipEndPoint;
                sendReceiveArgs.Completed += OnSend;
                var result = _socket.SendAsync(sendReceiveArgs);
                if (result)
                {
                    _autoSendReceiveEvents[SendOperation].WaitOne();
                }
            }
        }

##OnSend

    private void OnSend(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
            try
            {
                if (eventArgs.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
                {
                    CloseSocket();
                    _autoSendReceiveEvents[SendOperation].Set();
                }

                switch (eventArgs.LastOperation)
                {
                    case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:
                        _autoSendReceiveEvents[SendOperation].Set();
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CloseSocket();
                _autoSendReceiveEvents[SendOperation].Set();
            }
    }
```